# git lfs push is very slow

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a repo with one "big" file (~280 Mb), only this file is tracked by lfs. When I try to push it, push is extremely slow, around 20 KB/s - and if I wait, it only gets slower.

I tried using git for windows - `git version 2.28.0.windows.1` with `git-lfs/2.11.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.2; git 48b28d97)` and I tried Ubuntu with `git version 2.28.0` and `git-lfs/2.12.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.4)` - with equal results.

I also tried pushing by ssh and https, and setting `git config http.version HTTP/1.1` - no difference.

I'm pushing to github (not sure if that matters); bandwith limit doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For now my temporary solution is downgrading git (on ubuntu) to 2.17.1 and git-lfs to 2.3.4.